# flatten a variant type into columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column of type variant, but I don't know it's columns in advance.
I would like to "flatten" it into columns.

for example, if my table is:

```
+------------------------------------+
|                data                |
+------------------------------------+
| {a:1, b:2, c:{xx:"yy"}}            |
| {a:11, b:33, c:{zz:"qq"}, d="aaa"} |
+------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to get a table in the following structure:

```
+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
| a(int) | b(int) | c(variant) | d(string) |
+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
|      1 |      2 | {xx:"yy"}  | null      |
|     11 |     33 | {zz:"qq"}  | "aaa"   |
+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
```

is it possible to do this without knowing the structure of the `data` column in advance?

Comment: Just to understand the question, do you want automatically create a new table based on the data that you have from the first table?

Comment: not necessarily create a new table, just to have a way to extract all the columns. for example, it could be a table function (UTDF).

Comment: If d would be just "aaa" it looks like a simple task.

Comment: @MarkusZeller that was a mistake, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Without knwoing the structure of the data in advance, you need to use dynamic SQL :

```
WITH all_keys AS (
  SELECT 
    f.value:key::STRING AS key_name
  FROM your_table,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => data) f
  GROUP BY key_name
)
SELECT LISTAGG(key_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY key_name) AS keys
FROM all_keys;
```

Comment: this just gets all the available column names, not putting the values in columns

Comment: Yes, and then you use this SQL inside a Snowflake Scripting block (the dynamic SQL part) and generate the SQL the does a SELECT with the now found column names, so your data is extracted.